# JwtBearerAuthentication in AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer and refresh token

Tags: asp.net-core, token, jwt, claims-based-identity

I am using aspnetcore in visual studio 2015. 
I've implemented **JwtBearerAuthentication** and I am successfully using token authentication. So users login and get a token.

Now, my tokens have an expiration time span. After they expire, users can no longer be validated. I want to be able to refresh the user's token silently in the client a couple minutes before the expiration. How can I achieve so in this setup? Is it possible with **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer**?

Comment: I assume you are using WebApi (in contrast to MVC/Views), in this case your middleware will return http code 401 Unauthorized. Your client (the consumer of that api) will have to react on this and try to refresh/authenticate the user and get a new token, then repeat the previous request. This has nothing to do with the JwtBearer middleware

Comment: ok... where is it supposed to call to get that new token? Initial token is obtained with username and password

Comment: Where ever you got it. ASP.NET Core Identity can't issue JWT tokens, so you need a different middleware / library for it (ASOS/OpenIddict or IdentityServer4) or you use 3rd party OpenID/Oauth providers such as Google or Facebook, this is where you need to refresh the token if you obtained it from there. But your question lacks the necessary information, we have no idea where you got the JWT from ;)

Comment: I'm using a cutom middleware I managed to put together wrapping around  System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt... But after seeing the code I see I could handle another request to a custom address just like the first and reissue a new token myself, this time only based in the old token...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You can create a refresh-token (for example a random string) and set an expiration time more than your secret token. Send this token to your client, and save it in the client. Whenever the main token expires you can send the refresh token to server and check it, 
instead of sending the user to the login page (and creating a new token). 
If it has not expires yet, you create a new token and refresh token and set access to user, your header must contain:

```
This site says...
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJlUzl1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZ...",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 119,
    "refresh_token": "9b091854a9d3415c8ae12f07c333e5...",
}
```